# Node JS, detect production environment

Tags: node.js, batch-file

When I'm in dev mode I don't want my server to send email and some other stuff so I have this in server.js file:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
```

When I move it to production i change the value to 'production'.

Problem is of course that it is easy to forget on deployments. Is it possible somehow to detect when server is in production?

If it's not, is it possible to write a batch script that replaces a string in a file?

Comment: I use local config file, that not under git and extends main config. So any local key will replace main one.

Comment: You should not assign environment variable in the script.

Comment: Environment variables are typically only read by the script rather than being set. They're more often assigned within your OS settings or in a startup file such as a `.bashrc`. This lets you set `NODE_ENV` as `production` for all scripts run on your server -- `var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't manually change values of `process.env` object, because this object is reflecting your execution environment.

In your code you should do the following:

```
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
```

And then you launch your app in production like this:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

If `NODE_ENV` environment variable is not set, then it will be set to `development` by default.

You could also use [`dotenv` module](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) in development to specify all environment variables in a file.

Furthermore, I've implemented a reusable module, which allows to automatically detect environment by analyzing both CLI arguments and NODE_ENV variable. This could be useful on your development machine, because you can easily change environment by passing a CLI argument to you Node.js program like this: `$ node app.js --prod`. It's also nice to use with Gulp: `$ gulp build --prod`.

Please see more details and use cases on the [`detect-environment`'s page](https://github.com/betsol/detect-environment).

Answer (score 4):

The suggested way to tackle these kind of problems is by using the [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process) global object provided by NodeJS. For example:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
```

By the above line. We can easily switch between development / production environment. If we haven't configured any environment variable it works with development environment.

`process.env` is an object that contains the user environment.

For example if we are running our application in a bash shell and have configured `NODE_ENV` to `production`. Then i can access that in node application as `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

There are multiple ways to define this `NODE_ENV` variable for nodejs applications:

```
## Setting environment variable for bash shell
export NODE_ENV=production

## Defined while starting the application
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

So i don't think you would require any batch file for this. When handling multiple configuration variables, follow [this](https://gist.github.com/samarpanda/221f1d11d663aa1afa03).

Comment: @per-ström hope my answer helps.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'll try it on my next deploy. I accept if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally handled through configuration files (e.g. config frameworks like [node-convict](https://github.com/mozilla/node-convict)) and through environmental variables.  In the start command in production, you might do something like:

```
NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

then the `process.env.NODE_ENV` would be properly set by any module in your app that cares.